# How to display list of pins in Xamarin forms google maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display google maps with list of pins dynamically added(in future I will get them from Web API) i created list of positions(lang , lat) and passing them to list of pins but only item is shown

This is my code cs

```
public class LocationPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public LocationPageViewModel()
        {
            MabPosition = new Position(24.774265, 46.738586);

            Positions = new List<Position>();
            Positions.Add(new Position(24.774265, 46.738586));
            Positions.Add(new Position(24.928899, 46.376939));
            Positions.Add(new Position(25.774265, 47.738586));

            foreach (Position item in Positions )
            {
                PinCollection.Add(new Pin() { Position = item, Type = PinType.Generic , Label="Geddah"});
            }
        }

        private List<Position> _positions;
        public List<Position> Positions
        {
            get { return _positions; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _positions, value); }
        }

        private Position _mabPosition;
        public Position MabPosition
        {
            get { return _mabPosition; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _mabPosition, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Pin> _pinCollection = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
        public ObservableCollection<Pin> PinCollection {
            get { return _pinCollection; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _pinCollection, value); }
        }
    }
```

and my xaml

```
 <bindablemap:BindableMap MapType="Street" MapPosition="{Binding MabPosition}" MapPins="{Binding PinCollection}" ></bindablemap:BindableMap>
```

App display only one pin and i didn't know what's the problem 
[one pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxeSx.png)

Sorry for bad English

Comment: BindableMap is a third party control? Something you wrote? Any code details on that?

Comment: It works for me when i zoom out .. it's already displayed ^_^ thank u 
but anyway i followed this article https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-maps/